# HTML join with Ruby, How can i do this?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

how can i join the ruby code with the html code? I want that the html "href" link with the path (ruby). Could somebody help me? For example:  `<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li> , the href linked to Ruby <%= link_to "Home", root_path %> .`

Ill want that my Button Home, for example is linked with the Ruby root_path.

**HTML Code**

```
>  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
>           <div class="navbar-inner">
>             <div class="container">
>               <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
>                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
>                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
>                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
>               </a>
>               <a class="brand" href="#">My Workingtimes</a>
>               <div class="nav-collapse">
>                 <ul class="nav">
>                   <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
>                   <li><a href="#about">Log In</a></li>
>                   <li><a href="#contact">Sign In</a></li>
>                 </ul>
>               </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
>             </div>
>           </div>
>         </div>
```

**RUBY CODE**

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="content">
        <% if flash[:notice] %>
        <p id="notice">
            <%= flash[:notice] %>
        </p>
        <% end %>

        <% if flash[:alert] %>
        <p id= "alert">
            <%= flash[:alert] %> 
        </p>
        <% end %>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    <%= link_to "Home", root_path %> |
    <%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_path %> |
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <%= link_to "Logout", logout_path, method: :delete %> |
        <%= link_to "My Workingtimes", mytimes_path %>
        <% else %>
        <%= link_to "Login", login_path %>
        <% end %> 
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. What did you try? What exactly does not work as expected?

Comment: Are you want something like this? `<a href="#{root_path}">Home</a></li>`

Comment: You can not just enter the ruby code on any Html file. It has to be a .html.erb and it has to be parsed on the server side. so the location of the file in the Application structure is importent.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. It runs in my application.html.erb

Comment: <a href="#{root_path}">Home</a></li> It dont works. sorry

Comment: `<a href="<%= root_path %>">Home</a></li>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `rake routes` and see what, for instance, `root_path` points to.

Unless you haven't made any changes, it probably points to `/`, in which case you can have `href = "/"`

This is assuming that you *absolutely* need to enter the path name in the `HTML`.  Otherwise, I would highly recommend converting your `.html` to `.html.erb` and then use something like `<%= link_to "Home", root_path %>` as you had mentioned.

Comment: Maybe for better understanding. I want to realise my Ruby with Bootstrap. The html Code is from Bootstrap

Comment: <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>